# How to fit the image in tablet mode

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am displaying the carousel on my home page. So when I hit the tablet mode responsiveness the image is displayed only half-screen as shown in below

[image] .

On my pc screen, it displays properly

I have tried the below code for displaying the image using styled-components

```
    export const LegendImage = styled.img`
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
     `
```

Using that `LegendImage` i display it in the render component

```
<LegendImage src={item.banner.data.full_url} alt={item.title} />
```

PS: When You click on image you will get to know where the white space is

Answer (score 0):

don't give a "static" height.

i dont have tested it but try some like this:

```
$tablet: '767px';

@media (max-width $tablet) {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` for responsive design:

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```